# Declaring nested variables in Terraform for aws_instance resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am having issues declaring my nested variables. I have a .tfvars for my variables, then I declare it in varaibles.tf, and lastly, I have my aws instance resource looping through my variables. My issue is that my nested volume blocks in my .tfvars are not being declared and coming up as an error.

**terraform.tfvar**

```
instances = {
    instance-01a = {
        ami                   = "ami-abcdefghijk1234",
        type                  = "t3.medium"
        key_name              = "caws-dc-01"
        private_ip            = "10.0.0.5"
        subnet_id             = "subnet-abcdefghijk1234" #Temp
        vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-abcdefghijk1234"]     #Temp
        root_block_device = {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"
        volume_size = 100
        volume_type = "gp2"
        tags = {
            Name = "instance-01a /dev/sda1"
        }
        }
        ebs_block_device = {
        device_name = "/dev/sdf"
        volume_size = 50
        volume_type = "gp2"
        tags = {
            Name = "instance-01a /dev/sdf"
        }
        }
        disable_api_termination = true
        tags = {
        Name = "instance-01a"
        }
    }
```

**variable.tf**

`variable "instances" {}`

**instance.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "specific_instances" {
  for_each = var.instances

  ami                     = each.value["ami"]
  instance_type           = each.value["type"]
  key_name                = each.value["key_name"]
  private_ip              = each.value["private_ip"]
  subnet_id               = each.value["subnet_id"]              
  vpc_security_group_ids  = each.value["vpc_security_group_ids"] 
  root_block_device        = each.value["root_block_device"]
  ebs_block_device        = each.value["ebs_block_device"]
  disable_api_termination = each.value["disable_api_termination"]
  tags                    = each.value["tags"]
}
```

Error Message

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on instance.tf line 13, in resource "aws_instance" "specific_instances":
│   13:   root_block_device        = each.value["root_block_device"]
│
│ An argument named "root_block_device" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type
│ "root_block_device"?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on instance.tf line 14, in resource "aws_instance" "specific_instances":
│   14:   ebs_block_device        = each.value["ebs_block_device"]
│
│ An argument named "ebs_block_device" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type
│ "ebs_block_device"?
╵
```

Comment: Well, `root_block_device` isn't a single parameter, rather a block, `root_block_device {}`. Same applies for any `_block_device` type.

Comment: How would I declare variables in a block while still trying to loop through my `variable "instances" {}` ?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ebs_block_device](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#ebs_block_device) is a `block` not an argument. So it means you have to do the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "specific_instances" {
  for_each = var.instances

  # rest 
  # ....
  
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name =  each.value["ebs_block_device"]["device_name"]
    volume_size =  each.value["ebs_block_device"]["volume_size"]
    volume_type =  each.value["ebs_block_device"]["volume_type"]
    tags        =  each.value["ebs_block_device"]["tags"]
  }
}
```